# Convexity of partial variables of a convexfunction

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am new to the optimization theory and want to figure out the following problem about convexity.

Suppose that function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a convex function. Consider another function $f^{\prime}: \mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which satisfy the following conditions:

- $m<n$;
- For a fix $x_2\in\mathbb{R}^{n-m}$, which satisfy $\forall x_1\in dom(f^{\prime}), x=[x_1^T, x_2^T]^T\in dom(f)$, $g(x_2) = f(x)$;

Can we ensure that function $g$ is also convex?

---

The above mathematical formulation might be abstract. What I want to express here is that, if a function is convex in $\mathbb{R}^n$ space, can we prove that the function of the partial variable is still convex?

To make things clear, let us consider an example function $f$ which is defined in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The function $f$ calculate the squared norm of $x\in \mathbb{R}^3$, which is $x(1)^2+x(2)^2+x(3)^2$, so it is a convex function. Now, suppose that we fix $x(3) = 1$, then this function becomes $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, which is $x(1)^2+x(2)^2 + 1$. This function is also convex. My question is that if this property often holds?

BTW: I think the expression above the rule maybe a little bit ambiguous, can someone also help one better illustrate what I want to express in formal mathematical formulation?

Comment: You're on the right track, and you've got correct intuition! My only main qualm is with the notation -- it is common to use several inputs for $x$ to help demonstrate which variables are being held and which are not. For instance, if $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ is convex in $(x_1,...,x_n)$, then for any fixed $y_1$, then $f(y_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ remains convex in $(x_2,...,x_n)$. Have you tried proving this?

Comment: @Zim Thanks for the comments. I think the proof of the special case can be like this: Suppose we have two points $a = (y_1, x_{2a}, ..., x_{na})$ and $b = (y_1, x_{2b}, ..., x_{nb})$, if we can show that $f(ta+(1-t)b) \le tf(a)+(1-t)f(b)$, the convexity holds. I think this is true because this inequility holds in the view that $a$ and $b$ are in $(x_1,...,x_n)$ space. I happen to see that this proof may fit any cases where we can fit any variables.

Comment: Yup, you've got the right idea!